# Prove that $f_n \to f \ \mu$-a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$ s.t. $f_n \to f$ in $\mu$-measure and $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is increasing almost everywhere (*$\mu$-a.e.*)

Prove that $f_n \to f \ \mu$-a.e.

---

I was thinking of using monotone convergence somehow since the sequence is increasing but I can't quite make it work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hint: Convergence in measure implies convergence a.e. of a subsequence.

Comment: But then I end up with the following: $\int \vert f_n -f \vert d \mu = \int \lim_{k\to \infty} \vert f_n -f_{n_k} \vert d \mu $. However $ (\vert f_n -f_{n_k} \vert)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not strictly increasing or decreasing so I can't use monotone convergence. Or am I mistaken?